# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, t4

I'm using .Net Core 1.1
I want to generate some codes with T4 in Visual Studio 2017 15.1

**MultipleOutputHelper.ttinclude:**

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Core"#>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Linq"#>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE"#>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml"#>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.Linq"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text"#>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating"#>
<#+
// https://github.com/damieng/DamienGKit/tree/master/T4/MultipleOutputHelper
// http://damieng.com/blog/2009/11/06/multiple-outputs-from-t4-made-easy-revisited

// Manager class records the various blocks so it can split them up
class Manager {
    private class Block {
        public string Name;
        public int Start, Length;
        public bool IncludeInDefault;
    }

    private Block currentBlock;
    private readonly List<Block> files = new List<Block>();
    private readonly Block footer = new Block();
    private readonly Block header = new Block();
    private readonly ITextTemplatingEngineHost host;
    private readonly StringBuilder template;
    protected readonly List<string> generatedFileNames = new List<string>();

    public static Manager Create(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, StringBuilder template) {
        return (host is IServiceProvider) ? new VSManager(host, template) : new Manager(host, template);
    }

    public void StartNewFile(string name) {
        if (name == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        CurrentBlock = new Block { Name = name };
    }

    public void StartFooter(bool includeInDefault = true) {
        CurrentBlock = footer;
        footer.IncludeInDefault = includeInDefault;
    }

    public void StartHeader(bool includeInDefault = true) {
        CurrentBlock = header;
        header.IncludeInDefault = includeInDefault;
    }

    public void EndBlock() {
        if (CurrentBlock == null)
            return;
        CurrentBlock.Length = template.Length - CurrentBlock.Start;
        if (CurrentBlock != header && CurrentBlock != footer)
            files.Add(CurrentBlock);
        currentBlock = null;
    }

    public virtual void Process(bool split, bool sync = true) {
        if (!split) return;
        EndBlock();
        var headerText = template.ToString(header.Start, header.Length);
        var footerText = template.ToString(footer.Start, footer.Length);
        var outputPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(host.TemplateFile);
        files.Reverse();
        if (!footer.IncludeInDefault)
            template.Remove(footer.Start, footer.Length);
        foreach(var block in files) {
            var fileName = Path.Combine(outputPath, block.Name);
            var content = headerText + template.ToString(block.Start, block.Length) + footerText;
            generatedFileNames.Add(fileName);
            CreateFile(fileName, content);
            template.Remove(block.Start, block.Length);
        }
        if (!header.IncludeInDefault)
            template.Remove(header.Start, header.Length);
    }

    protected virtual void CreateFile(string fileName, string content) {
        if (IsFileContentDifferent(fileName, content))
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, content, Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public virtual string GetCustomToolNamespace(string fileName) {
        return null;
    }

    public virtual string DefaultProjectNamespace {
        get { return null; }
    }

    protected bool IsFileContentDifferent(string fileName, string newContent) {
        return !(File.Exists(fileName) && File.ReadAllText(fileName) == newContent);
    }

    private Manager(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, StringBuilder template) {
        this.host = host;
        this.template = template;
    }

    private Block CurrentBlock {
        get { return currentBlock; }
        set {
            if (CurrentBlock != null)
                EndBlock();
            if (value != null)
                value.Start = template.Length;
            currentBlock = value;
        }
    }

    private class VSManager: Manager {
        private readonly ProjectItem templateProjectItem;
        private readonly DTE dte;
        private readonly Action<string> checkOutAction;
        private readonly Action<List<string>> projectSyncAction;

        public override string DefaultProjectNamespace {
            get {
                return templateProjectItem.ContainingProject.Properties.Item("DefaultNamespace").Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        public override string GetCustomToolNamespace(string fileName) {
            return dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(fileName).Properties.Item("CustomToolNamespace").Value.ToString();
        }

        public override void Process(bool split, bool sync) {
            if (templateProjectItem.ProjectItems == null)
                return;
            base.Process(split, sync);
            if (sync)
                projectSyncAction.EndInvoke(projectSyncAction.BeginInvoke(generatedFileNames, null, null));
        }

        protected override void CreateFile(string fileName, string content) {
            if (IsFileContentDifferent(fileName, content)) {
                CheckoutFileIfRequired(fileName);
                File.WriteAllText(fileName, content, Encoding.UTF8);
            }
        }

        internal VSManager(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, StringBuilder template)
            : base(host, template) {
            var hostServiceProvider = (IServiceProvider)host;
            dte = (DTE) hostServiceProvider?.GetService(typeof(DTE)) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Could not obtain IServiceProvider");
            if (dte == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Could not obtain DTE from host");
            templateProjectItem = dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(host.TemplateFile);
            checkOutAction = fileName => dte.SourceControl.CheckOutItem(fileName);
            projectSyncAction = keepFileNames => ProjectSync(templateProjectItem, keepFileNames);
        }

        private static void ProjectSync(ProjectItem templateProjectItem, List<string> keepFileNames) {
            var keepFileNameSet = new HashSet<string>(keepFileNames);
            var projectFiles = new Dictionary<string, ProjectItem>();
            var originalFilePrefix = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(templateProjectItem.FileNames[0]) + ".";
            foreach (ProjectItem projectItem in templateProjectItem.ProjectItems)
                projectFiles.Add(projectItem.FileNames[0], projectItem);

            // Remove unused items from the project
            foreach (var pair in projectFiles)
                if (!keepFileNames.Contains(pair.Key) && !(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pair.Key) + ".").StartsWith(originalFilePrefix))
                    pair.Value.Delete();

            // Add missing files to the project
            foreach(var fileName in keepFileNameSet)
                if (!projectFiles.ContainsKey(fileName))
                    templateProjectItem.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(fileName);
        }

        private void CheckoutFileIfRequired(string fileName) {
            var sc = dte.SourceControl;
            if (sc != null && sc.IsItemUnderSCC(fileName) && !sc.IsItemCheckedOut(fileName))
                checkOutAction.EndInvoke(checkOutAction.BeginInvoke(fileName, null, null));
        }
    }
}
#>
```

**CreatingBusinessComponentsT4.txt:**

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ include file="MultipleOutputHelper.ttinclude" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)Smartiz3.Data\bin\Debug\Smartiz3.Data.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="Smartiz3.Data" #>
// By Mohammad Dayyan
<#
var manager = Manager.Create(Host, GenerationEnvironment);
var @namespace = "Smartiz3.Data";

var assembly = typeof(Smartiz3.Data.Color).Assembly;
var allEntityTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace).ToArray();
foreach (var entity in allEntityTypes)
{
    var entityName = string.Format("{0}{1}", entity.Name[0].ToString().ToLower(), entity.Name.Remove(0,1));
    manager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + "BusinessComponent.cs");
    #>
using Smartiz3.Business;

namespace Smartiz3.BusinessComponent
{
    public class <#= entity.Name #>BusinessComponent : BaseBusinessComponent
    {
        private readonly <#= entity.Name #>BusinessObject _<#= entityName #>BusinessObject;
        public <#= entity.Name #>BusinessComponent(<#= entity.Name #>BusinessObject <#= entityName #>BusinessObject)
        {
            _<#= entityName #>BusinessObject = <#= entityName #>BusinessObject;
        }

        public BusinessObject<<#= entity.Name #>, int> BusinessObject => _<#= entityName #>BusinessObject;

    }
}<#
    manager.EndBlock();
}

#>
<# manager.Process(true); #>
```

I just used above files to generate codes in .Net 4.6.2 and everything was OK, but in .Net Core I get the following error:

**Error:**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating5D169A44428EC29244069AAD45E449C1543F4B7B59370718992CE3B48758ABBC59FA6B5E2E3A51DF677FEEC8725FA416A706310BDCF6326AC2BD2FD2C19339F3.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.PerformTransformation()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. BusinessComponent   D:\...\CreatingBusinessComponentsT4.tt  1
```

I installed the following package, but nothing change:
`System.IO` 4.3
`System.IO.FileSystem` 4.3

How can I resolve it?